# Is the integral function of a $L^2[0,1]$ function continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

If we have $f(x) \in L^2[0,1]$, is $\int_0^x f(y)dy : x\in [0,1]$ a continuous function of x? If we were working with a Riemann integrable function, this would be true, but what about Lebesgue integrable functions? If $\int_0^x f(y)dy : x\in [0,1]$, is not continuous, then can we say it is at least continuous almost everywhere?

Comment: It is even Holder continuous: $|g(y) - g(x) | \le  \int _x^y |f(t)| dt \le |x-y|^{1/2} \|f\|_{L^2}$.

Comment: @ArcticChar was the last inequality just Holders inequality?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @ArcticChar you should post this as an answer, then Bill can close the question.